# Tag download don't work

Tags: php, download

I found a problem on my site today. The download button does not seem to be working anymore. The button that calls up the mp4 link via the tag "download", should download the file. It worked before without problems, but today it doesn’t download and I do not understand why.
Here is the code;

```
<a href="<?php echo $video; ?>" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Do you have the `PHP` code where `$video` is filled?

Comment: We need to see all the relevant source code. Did you look in the PHP logs for any error messages? When you say "not working" do you mean the page is displayed but the link is invalid, the link is correct but doesn't work or something else?